# How do I find and extract two lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a large text file in which each two rows of data belong to one person.

For example:

```
RS08CO 000000000 Jane Doe
RW8578789654130000000
```

I need to be able to search for 'RS08CO' and grab the line beginning with RS08CO AND RW857878 ...

Any gurus out there have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Simply search for:

```
^RS08CO.*\n^.*$
```

This looks for `RS08CO` at the start of a line, then matches everything (`.*\n`) up to the end-of-line and the whole of the following line (`^.*$`). You will need to enable Regular Expressions.